# Scroll to position on page for category pages only -- woocommerce

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a "shop" page using woocommerce. I have categories for my products. When someone selects a category they're essentially sent to the same "shop" page just now it's filtered to only that category of products. I'm sure you know how this works.

However, they shouldn't have to scroll down the page again to get to the product catalog section. The page should just scroll/jump automatically to the product catalog section (for category pages only).

How do I do this? (see wireframe below)

[image]

Comment: Okay, maybe I made this too confusing. Do you know how on-page links jump you to a certain point on a page? That's what I want, except I need this to be integrated with woocommerce categories... so that anytime a category is selected, you are directed to that category page and then to a certain point on the page. Make sense?